# "finally as it seemed to me" -- what is "as it seemed"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, comparative

> But Elijah passed on, without seeming to notice us. This relieved me; and once more, and finally as it seemed to me, I pronounced him in my heart, a humbug.
>   <sub>(from *Moby Dick* [Source](http://americanliterature.com/author/herman-melville/book/moby-dick-or-the-whale/chapter-19-the-prophet))</sub>

What does "as it seemed to me" mean here?

Comment: It means "he seemed like a humbug to me".

Comment: I urge anyone who has downvoted or closevoted this question to reconsider. It's a paradigmatic Learner crux. This *as* is a very difficult word to interpret, and the "definitions" given in the five online dictionaries I've consulted -- OALD, ODO, Collins, AHD and M-W -- are quite hopeless to anyone who doesn't already know what is meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
*As it seemed to me* modifies *finally*. Paraphrase:

> I pronounced him a humbug, again and (this is how it appeared to me at the time:) finally.

**LONG ANSWER:**
*As* is a very short word with a very long and complicated history: the first edition of the *Oxford English Dictionary* gave 69 distinct uses, most of which are still current. The one employed here appears as definition 26 under branch VI. of section B.

> **B.** In a subordinate sentence, as a **Relative or Conjunctive Adverb**, introducing a clause** which expresses I. II. the *mode* (manner and degree), whence also III. the *time*, *place*, IV. *reason*, V. *purpose*, *result* of the principal sentence; **passing into VI. a relative pronoun, a relative particle ...**  [emphasis mine]
>
> **VI**. Introducing an attributive clause ...
>
> **26.** In parenthetic clauses, affirming, explaining, or commenting on a word in the principal sentence... ([LINK](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/478/mode/2up), see the bottom of page 479, column 2)

The term “relative particle” shows the editor, James Murray, throwing his hands up in despair at the impossibility of making this *as* fit into the familiar part-of-speech categories; but it’s not at all a bad choice. *As* isn’t exactly a conjunction and it isn’t exactly an adverb, but it **is** a ‘relative’ *something*: it refers to its antecedent, the adverb *finally*, in the same way as a relative pronoun refers to an antecedent NP (noun phrase), and the clause it heads ‘comments’ on *finally* in the same way as an ordinary relative clause modifies its antecedent. It may be paraphrased as *which is how*:

> ... and finally (***which is how*** it seemed to me) ...

In this context it has the force of qualifying the word *finally*: Ishmael is taking care to let you know that this wasn’t actually his final judgment on Elijah, it only seemed to him at the time that it would be his final judgment.

Comment: @birdman1234- what something *seems* to you is what you *think* it is.  If something *seems* dirty to you, then you *think* it's dirty.

Comment: So this is the same as the "as" in this sentence from "The Prophet" of Moby dick? " But it was startling to see this excellent hearted Quakeress coming on board, as she did the last day, with a long oil-ladle in one hand, and still longer whaling lance in the other."

Comment: @birdman1234 1) 'as she did...' is the same *as*  2) 'as will help you' is not; this is a *such ... as* construction. 3) *You* may point it so; but Melville (like most Real Writers) points rhetorically rather than mechanically; he 'hears' *and finally as it seemed to me* as a single unit, with the stress topping on *finally* and falling off rapidly from there. He comma-brackets this entire unit and doesn't want to confuse the reader with another comma in the middle.

Comment: This is like "He is an American, as is obvious from his accent" ?

Comment: @birdman Yes. With a long oil-ladle is how she came on board the last day. That he is American is obvious from his accent.

Comment: I see. But I think a comma should be before "as" because this is like, "America, which is the biggest military country in the world, is...."

Comment: @birdman1234 Yes, ordinarily, but if Melville puts a comma there he closes his comma bracket too early. The point of pointing is to make the structure clear, not to conform to mechanical rules.

Comment: If this sentence were just "Finally as it seemed to me,..." should it be, "Finally, as it seemed to me,...."?

Comment: @birdman1234 Yes.